# Amazon product api with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services

I'm a newbie with Angular. I tried to consume amazon webservice. But for something but I keep getting an InvalidClientTokenId and Signature. Here is my jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L7fnozuo/24/

```
console.log(search)

$http.jsonp(URL)

.success(function(data) {
    $scope.jsonObject = data;
    $scope.items = data.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
});
```

Comment: How are you supposed to generate the signature?

Comment: What does google say about that error?

Comment: in your GET request, you're actually supplying the value for this `AWSAccessKeyId=` right?

Comment: @ShehryarAbbasi Yes I am supplying the value for the AWSAccessKeyId.

Comment: so, setting the code aside for now, if you were to compose the whole URL .with all the tokens, ids, accessKeys and your query etc, and paste it directly in the browser, it returns the expected data correctly and without errors?

Comment: @ShehryarAbbasi No, Isnt working

Comment: okay, if the URL itself doesnt work then its probably not your code - you may need to figure out if you're providing the InvalidClientTokenId and Signature values correctly (maybe there is a typo in the value) or you maybe they have expired and need to be recreated or requested again from your Developer account with AWS. GL!

Comment: @ShehryarAbbasi I think it my Signature but Idk how to implement it.